# Keep similar rows pandas dataframe with maximum overlap

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, overlap

I have a question for which I have 
 a dataframe which looks like (example):

```
   index  ID   time     value
   0      1     2h       10
   1      1     2.15h    15
   2      1     2.30h    5
   3      1     2.45h    24
   4      2     2.15h    6
   5      2     2.30h    12
   6      2     2.45h    18
   7      3     2.15h    2
   8      3     2.30h    1
```

I would like to keep the maximum number of ID row overlapping. 
So:

```
   index  ID   time    value
   1      1     2.15h   15
   2      1     2.30h    5
   4      2     2.15h    6
   5      2     2.30h   12
   7      3     2.15h    2
   8      3     2.30h    1
```

I know I can create a df with unique times and then merge each ID separately to it and then keep all rows with all IDs filled for each time but this is quite impractical. I have looked but have not found an answer for a possible smarter way. Does someone have an idea how to make this more practical?

Comment: Not clear to me what you are doing. Can you explain clearly: `I would like to keep the maximum number of ID row overlapping.`

Comment: In the example you see that there are multiple ID, time combinations. However. Only a few times (namely 2.15h and 2.30h) seem to overlap among the IDs. I would like to keep only these rows for the IDs. This while ID 1 has ''the most''  different times (2h, 2.15h, 2.30h, 2.45h) but there are only 2 (that is in this example the maximum) which overlap with 2 other IDs (namely 2 and 3). Hope I made this clear in this way. I am quite new to posting/stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
cols = df.groupby(['ID', 'time']).size().unstack().dropna(axis=1).columns

df = df[df['time'].isin(cols)]
print (df)
   ID   time  value
1   1  2.15h     15
2   1  2.30h      5
4   2  2.15h      6
5   2  2.30h     12
7   3  2.15h      2
8   3  2.30h      1
```

**Details**:

First aggregate `DataFrame` by [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), then reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) - `NaN`s are created for non overlapping values:

```
print (df.groupby(['ID', 'time']).size().unstack())
time  2.15h  2.30h  2.45h   2h
ID                            
1       1.0    1.0    1.0  1.0
2       1.0    1.0    1.0  NaN
3       1.0    1.0    NaN  NaN
```

Remove columns with [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and get columns names:

```
print (df.groupby(['ID', 'time']).size().unstack().dropna(axis=1))
time  2.15h  2.30h
ID                
1       1.0    1.0
2       1.0    1.0
3       1.0    1.0
```

And last filter list by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['time'].isin(cols)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear anwer! Especially the detailed steps so I could learn step by step what happened and to adjust a small bit to your example code to exactly fit. That is for my real data I only needed df = df[df['time'].isin(cols) to keep all overlapping time periods. Otherwise I only got the first time period overlapping and the last period overlapping while in between there was also overlap